# why does scala's implicit lookup ignore companion object of nested class

Tags: scala, nested, implicit, companion-object, path-dependent-type

I was playing around with the following piece of code:

```
class A
class B
class C

trait Codecs[L] {
    case class Codec[R](val code: L => R, val decode: R => L)
    object Codec

    def code[R](foo: L)(implicit codec: Codec[R]): R = codec.code(foo)
    def decode[R](bar: R)(implicit codec: Codec[R]): L = codec.decode(bar)
}

object Codecs {
    implicit object ACodecs extends Codecs[A] {
        object Codec {
            implicit val ab: Codec[B] = new Codec(_ => new B, _ => new A)
            implicit val ac: Codec[C] = new Codec(_ => new C, _ => new A)
        }
    }
}

object test extends App {
    val codecs = implicitly[Codecs[A]]
    codecs.code[B](new A)
}
```

It won't compile, as the compiler is unable to find an implicit value of type `Codecs.Codec[B]`. 
As I understand, the two values `ab` and `ac` are of type `Acodecs.Codec[_]`(or something like that), which isn't exactly what the compiler is looking for. I am also aware that moving the case class `Codec[_]` and its companion outside of the trait solves the problem (after making it take 2 type params). If an implicit value is required, the compiler should include the companion object of the required type in the implicit scope.  My questions are:

1. How do I point the compiler at the companion of a path-dependent subtype, more specifically:
2. Is it possible to alter the signature of the two methods of the `trait` (ideally alter the type signature of the implicit param) to make this compile? How would one refer to the type `Acodecs.Codec[_]` from inside the trait `Codecs[_]`?
3. Like, how do you do this typeclass thing on a  nested  type?
4. Is there like a pattern or something dealing with this sort of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your type is bound to a specific instance since it's an inner class. And the compiler doesn't know that `implicitly[Codecs[A]]` is giving the exact same instance as what it's finding implicitly on the next line. For instance, if you pass it explicitly:

```
codecs.code[B](new A)(Codecs.ACodecs.Codec.ab)
```

You get this error message:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Codecs.ACodecs.Codec[B]
 required: codecs.Codec[B]
```

So it believes the enclosing instances to be possibly different, and so different types.

I've never really seen this specific kind of nesting of implicits - i.e. an implicit typeclass with path-dependent implicit typeclasses within it. So I doubt there's a pattern for dealing with it and would in fact kind of recommend against it. It seems overly complicated. Here's how I would personally treat this case:

```
case class Codec[L, R](val code: L => R, val decode: R => L)

trait Codecs[L] {
  type LocalCodec[R] = Codec[L, R]

  def code[R](foo: L)(implicit codec: LocalCodec[R]): R = codec.code(foo)
  def decode[R](bar: R)(implicit codec: LocalCodec[R]): L = codec.decode(bar)
}

object Codecs {
  implicit object ACodecs extends Codecs[A] {
    implicit val ab: LocalCodec[B] = new LocalCodec(_ => new B, _ => new A)
    implicit val ac: LocalCodec[C] = new LocalCodec(_ => new C, _ => new A)
  }
}

object test extends App {
  import Codecs.ACodecs._
  val codecs = implicitly[Codecs[A]]    
  codecs.code[B](new A)
}
```

You still get the benefit of a "half-narrowed" type to work with but it's just a type alias so there's no path-dependency issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What lead me to this code is that I wanted to avoid call-site imports. As it [turns out](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1493), nested classes don't (won't) have companions, no typeclass nesting for me.